# Passing variables to template rendering

Tags: blocks

I want to render "file-video.html.twig" template.

This is the documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21templates%21file-video.html.twig/9.3.x

This is my code:

```
 return [
                        '#theme' => 'file_video',
                        '#attributes' => ['TEST ATTR'],
                        '#files' => [
                            [
                                'file' => $file,
                                'source_attributes' => [
                                    
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ];
```

Where $file is Drupal\file\Entity\File. I tried 'source_attributes' => ['src' => $url], ... But everything in this array throws an error.

The problem seems that those are not variables passed to the correct template I want. The #attributes TEST ATTR goes into block div id instead of the template.

The correct template IS rendered, but nothing is passed to is. How should I format the return array in order to pass the variables into the template I want? I searched for couple hours and did not find any documentation whatsoever about this.

Comment: Please add to the question how the file media field and your block are connected. If the field is part of a custom block type you need to hook in the entity build process and not the block build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check:
`core/modules/file/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/FileMediaFormatterBase.php`
where 'source_attributes' is a `Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute` object.

```
 * @return array
 *   Numerically indexed array, which again contains an associative array with
 *  the following key/values:
 *     - file => \Drupal\file\Entity\File
 *     - source_attributes => \Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute
```

I forgot about your '#attributes'

Try:

```
'#attributes' => ['TEST' => ['ATTR']]
```

Comment: I think I have problem in how to pass the array from Block build() function. It seems that even when I am calling the template "file_video", the "attributes" parameter is "eaten" somewhere else, before rendering the correct template. It is not passed to the "file-video.html.twig", but to the block template, so the final HTML looks like <div "TEST"="ATTR"> .... _FILE-VIDEO.HTML.TWIG_.... </div>

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this out in a block and can 100% confirm it works:

```
use Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

$file = File::load(60);
$attributes = new Attribute();
$attributes->setAttribute('src', '/sites/default/files/MYVIDPATHHERE.mp4');
$build['vid'] = [
  '#theme' => 'file_video',
  '#attributes' => ['asda' => 'aa'],
  '#files' => [
    [
      'file' => $file,
      'source_attributes' => $attributes,
    ],
  ],
  '#cache' => ['tags' => []],
];
```

Which results in HTMl of:

```
<video asda="aa">
  <source src="/sites/default/files/MYVIDPATHHERE.mp4">
</video>
```

Obviously you could retreive the video src from $file, rather than just hard coding it like I have.

If the above code isn't working for you then you've got something else going on interferring with the rendering